# Trying to use nested forms with has_many :through in Rails 4 and getting duplicate join model entries

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, has-many-through

## Objective

To save a contract with a manifest of products using `has_many :through` and nested attributes.

## Problem

When the contract gets saved the product gets created properly and manifests gets created twice, once with the quantity but not the associations and again with the associations but no quantity.

## Details

### System Information

- **Operating System**: 10.9.3
- **Ruby Version**: `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]`
- **Rails Version**: `Rails 4.0.2`

### Models

#### Contract

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :manifests, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :products, through: :manifests

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end
```

#### Manifest

```
class Manifest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :product
end
```

#### Product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :manifests
    has_many :contracts, through: :manifests

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :manifests
end
```

#### ContractsController

```
class ContractsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contract, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /contracts
  # GET /contracts.json
  def index
    @contracts = Contract.all
  end

  # GET /contracts/1
  # GET /contracts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /contracts/new
  def new
    @contract = Contract.new
    product =  @contract.products.build
    manifest = product.manifests.build
  end

  # GET /contracts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /contracts
  # POST /contracts.json
  def create
    @contract = Contract.new(contract_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contract.save
        format.html { redirect_to @contract, notice: 'Contract was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @contract }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @contract.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_contract
      @contract = Contract.find(params[:id])
      @manifests = @contract.manifests
      @products = @contract.products
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def contract_params
      safe_manifests_attributes = [
        manifests_attributes: [
          :id,
          :quantity
        ]
      ]

      safe_products_attributes = [
        products_attributes: [
          :id,
          :sku,
          :name,
          :description,
          :unit_price,
          safe_manifests_attributes
        ]
      ]
      params.require(:contract).permit(:name, :description, safe_products_attributes)
    end
end
```

#### Form

```
= form_for @contract do |f|
- if @contract.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
    %h2= "#{pluralize(@contract.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this contract from being saved:"
    %ul
      - @contract.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg

.field
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name
.field
  = f.label :description
  %br/ 
  = f.text_area :description

%fieldset
  = f.fields_for :products do |product_builder|
    .field
      = product_builder.label :sku
      = product_builder.text_field :sku
    .field
      = product_builder.label :name
      = product_builder.text_field :name
    .field
      = product_builder.label :description
      %br/ 
      = product_builder.text_area :description
    .field
      = product_builder.label :unit_price
      = product_builder.text_field :unit_price
    = product_builder.fields_for :manifests do |manifest_builder|
      .field
        = manifest_builder.label :quantity
        = manifest_builder.number_field :quantity

.actions
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

#### Parameters and Inserts

```
Started POST "/contracts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-06 11:39:43 -0500
Processing by ContractsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"W1FTKbimANj6SzkpPsyVV1BD7RU9PHVvFYWOdSdXmJU=", "contract"=>{"name"=>"Testing Contract", "description"=>"A test", "products_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"sku"=>"mas-001", "name"=>"Product Test", "description"=>"Products description", "unit_price"=>"100.50", "manifests_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>"3"}}}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "contracts" ("created_at", "description", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2014 16:39:43 UTC +00:00], ["description", "A test"], ["name", "Testing Contract"], ["updated_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2014 16:39:43 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("created_at", "description", "name", "sku", "unit_price", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2014 16:39:43 UTC +00:00], ["description", "Products description"], ["name", "Product Test"], ["sku", "mas-001"], ["unit_price", 100.5], ["updated_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2014 16:39:43 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (2.9ms)  INSERT INTO "manifests" ("created_at", "product_id", "quantity", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2014 16:39:43 UTC +00:00], ["product_id", 4], ["quantity", 3], ["updated_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2014 16:39:43 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "manifests" ("contract_id", "created_at", "product_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["contract_id", 6], ["created_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2014 16:39:43 UTC +00:00], ["product_id", 4], ["updated_at", Fri, 06 Jun 2014 16:39:43 UTC +00:00]]
   (4.7ms)  commit transaction
```

---

As you can see, the manifest records are being created twice. The other problem is that those two manifest records look like this:

```
Manifest.last(2)
  Manifest Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "manifests".* FROM "manifests" ORDER BY "manifests"."id" DESC LIMIT 2
 => [#<Manifest id: 5, contract_id: nil, product_id: 4, quantity: 3, created_at: "2014-06-06 16:39:43", updated_at: "2014-06-06 16:39:43">, #<Manifest id: 6, contract_id: 6, product_id: 4, quantity: nil, created_at: "2014-06-06 16:39:43", updated_at: "2014-06-06 16:39:43">]
```

The first one was created with the `quantity` set but no associations saved. The second is created with the appropriate associations but *not* the `quantity`.

What am I missing? I'm sure it's something small or silly but I've been smashing my head against this wall for sometime so I'm hoping that the amazing (and smart) Stack Overflow community can help me figure this out. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Disregard the spacing in the form ... I didn't indent it properly in this post.

Answer (score 1):

**PROBABLY DOESN'T WORK**

Try this:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :manifests, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: contract
  has_many :products, through: :manifests
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end
```

According to this write-up (http://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through), you have to specify this inverse relation to get the foreign keys properly set. From the article,

> When you use `collection=` assignment with a has-many-through (as `accepts_nested_attributes_for` does), you have to specify `inverse_of` for Rails to save everything correctly.

**EDIT**

Can you change the `fields_for` wrappings in your user form? This seems like a tricky situation, since you're building the manifest from the product, and the product has no notion of a direct contract owner. If you could do:

```
def new
  @contract = Contract.new
  manifest =  @contract.manifests.build
  product = manifest.products.build
end
```

And then:

```
= f.fields_for :manifests do |manifest_builder|
  = manifest_builder.fields_for :products do |product_builder|
    # etc.
```

Then everything should save correctly (since the foreign keys can trickle down). This also seems to make more sense logically.

Otherwise, you might be able to modify your `create` action like:

```
@contract = Contract.new(contract_params)
@contract.products.first.manifests.first.contract = @contract
```

But that seems kind of hacky.

Comment: Hmmm. I'd seen that mentioned in a few places but wasn't sure if my use case matched. I'll give it a shot and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Nope. No change. :( I'll do some more reading on this option though and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @ZacharyAbresch, I updated my answer with a couple other possible solutions.